# Perl: Making a general function for handling tables take the table name as an input

Tags: perl, dbi

I have 20 tables and I'm trying to add a search function to my "model" that returns values in rows for the table a user chooses in the "view" part.

```
sub search {
my ( $table, $page_no, $search_value, $where, $order ) =
  @args{qw/table page_no search_value where order/};           
my $option = {};
  if ( defined $order || defined $self->order ) {
     $option->{order_by} = $order // $self->order;
  }      
my @rows = $self->ds->select( $where, $option );
return ( \@rows );
}
```

Unfortunately, my "ds" method (which relies on SQL::Abstract to do queries) is too general:

```
 sub ds { DataSource->new(); }
```

I have specific modules that use DataSource.pm (my general DBI module) as a parent and specify ds. If, for example, I want to modify table A, I would need to call:

```
 sub ds { DataSource->TableA->new(); }
```

My problem is that in this case I don't know a priori what table the user will want to modify, therefore I don't know what value `$table` will take. I want to write something that takes `$table` as an input and gives the respective ds. If `$table` is `TableA`, ds would need to become `sub ds { DataSource->TableA->new(); }`, if `$table` is `TableB`, ds would need to become `sub ds { DataSource->TableB->new(); }` and so on. How can I write this without relying on lots of conditionals, I wonder?

Unfortunately I can't modify ds. I would love to rely on Teng for this one...

Comment: Would storing a method name in a variable help you? `DataSource->$tablename->new;` is valid Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call methods using variables. If your table name is in $table, then you can use.

```
DataSource->$table->new();
```